# ASP.NET Webapi post file throws an IOException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have done a small Webapi that exposes a POST action. I have created a custom `MultipartFileStreamProvider` to deal with the payload and store the files. The problem occurs when I send a huge amount of files ( more precisely sending 1500 files one at a time sequentially). In my override method `ExecutePostProcessingAsync` I have the following line that try to read the file

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(file.LocalFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

but It throws an `IOException`

```
"The process cannot access the file"
```

for very few of them(usually one or two files out of 1500). I have no idea who has a lock on it (probably IIS or asp.net)

Any advises ( I can probably add a some retry after 10ms but would like to have a proper understanding of what is going wrong and how to properly handled these files uploads)

Comment: you are probably hitting the following known issue: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/282. Are you using the latest version of released bits(which has this fix)?

Comment: @KiranChalla: This is the exact same issue and I am happy to see that i came to roughly the same workaround. Thanks very much for pointing me out this issue.

Comment: No problem...Which version of bits are you using?

Comment: I am trying to open the file and retry many times (RetryUntilFileReadable)